# Is there any Querydsl like support present for Solr

Tags: solr, spring-data, querydsl, spring-data-solr

I am using Spring Data solr for implementing solr search in our project, and our search criteria is dynamic which can change according to the fields user enters.

I have gone to the official site of querydsl but it seems like they support lucene queries not solr, I have two questions

1. Is there any support querydsl queries present for solr or not,
2. And if it does not support is there any querydsl like support present to generate these dynamic queries for solr.

I tried the criteria api of solr but it does not solve the complexity I have in our project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet implemented. You can find a ticket for this here:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-260